# Can I use the child_process to spawn multiple python outputs on a server?

Tags: python, node.js, child-process, spawn

I am trying to use NodeJS to execute multiple python scripts and send the contents of those scripts to a local host. I would like to not be specific to the exact python script, but to use something similar to executing python script that uses ".py".

I have tried to run multiple processes, but the last one overwrote the former on the localhost.

Python scripts:

hellothere.py

```
 print("hello there")
```

helloworld.py

```
 print("Hello World!")
```

Goodbye.py

```
 print("Goodbye!")
```

Pythonspawn.js

```
var express = require('express');

var app = express();

app.get('/name', function callName(req, res) {

    var spawn = require("child_process").spawn;

            var PythonProcess1 = spawn('python',["./hellothere.py"] );
            var PythonProcess2 = spawn('python', ['./helloworld.py']);
            var PythonProcess3 = spawn('python', ['./Goodbye.py']);
            PythonProcess1.stdout.on('data', function(data) {
            res.send(data.toString());
            })
            PythonProcess2.stdout.on('data', function(data) {
            res.send(data.toString());            
            })
            PythonProcess3.stdout.on('data', function(data) {
            res.send(data.toString());            
            })
        }
})   
app.listen(1820, function() {
    console.log('Server is running on port %d.', this.address().port);
})
```

I would like to execute any python script that uses ".py" rather than specifying the exact script I want executed. If possible, I would like to also execute the scripts if they have a different amount of arguments. (I.e if helloworld.py had two sys.arg[i] and Goodbye.py had one sys.arg[i].)

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of exec() here, Here I am checking for all the .js files in the current working directory executing it all and add the result in an array and finally returning it.

```
const { exec } = require('child_process');

var result = [];
exec('ls | grep .js', (error, stdout, stderr) => {
  if (error) {
    console.error(`exec error: ${error}`);
    return;
  }
  var s = stdout.split('\n');
  s.pop();
  console.log(s);
  executeFiles(s);
});

function executeFiles(filenames) {
  filenames.forEach((element, index) => {
    exec(`node ${element}`, (error, stdout, stderr) => {
      if (error) {
        console.error(`exec error: ${error}`);
        return;
      }
      console.log(stdout);
      result.push(stdout.toString());
      if (index === filenames.length - 1) {
        console.log(result);
        return result;
      }
    });
  });
}
```

Comment: Can you explain how you tested it? I am getting exec error: Error: Command failed: node 06/10/2019.